# Lost material textures in Blender 2.83

Tags: texturing, materials

I've been working on a file with Blender 2.7. The file included several materials with textures, that had been mapped on objects using UV maps.

After upgrading to 2.83, all my materials are still there but have no texture associated to them. If I go to the Texture properties panel I can see the textures with a "0" (as if nobody was using them).

I know about the Nodes editor, but I wonder whether I can just use textures. I have to export this model to FBX, and I'm not sure how I would use nodes to map textures on models.

Answer (score 1):

You can have Blender attempt to locate the missing files under the external data section of the File menu. See image below:

[image: FindExternal]

If, on the other hand, you need to reconnect the textures manually, you can do so by selecting the material and going to the SHADING tab. From there, if there is no image texture, add one, and connect it as in the image below. This example is a very basic setup for a single image. If your material is PBR and there are other texture maps, add them and connect them to their respective inputs on the Principled BSDF. NOTE - make sure to select a non-color space for Normal, Displacement, Metallic and Roughness maps.

[image: SimpleTextureConnect]

Comment: But the textures have 0 users! How do I associate a texture to a material, as it did before (2.79)?

Comment: Do you still have the files on your computer? If so, I can show you how to restore them. Are they single image textures, or are they full PBR materials?

Comment: Single image textures. And, lucky for me, the files was versioned and I still have the 2.79 file.

Comment: I edited my answer to include the connection for the files. Alternatively, since you have the 2.79 file, you could always try going to `File > External Data > Pack All Into Blend`, save it and try opening again with 2.8+

Comment: Still nothing. I set the image as Base Color of my material, I have the UV map (so the migration didn't lose it), but I can't let the texture show. I'm seriously thinking of going back to 2.79 for this project only. I need to export to FBX, and I've heard bad things about node materials not being exported.

Comment: That's strange. One thing you could try is adding a new material to the material slot - hooking up the texture in the new material, and then swapping which material is active in the slot. This will keep the positioning of the texture where it should be, while switching for a "fresh copy"