# Reproduce texture relationships from 2.69, in 3.4.1

Tags: node-editor, shader-nodes, versions

How can I *discover and replicate*, using Blender 3.4.1, the Texture attachments to Material nodes that are shown in the same document in Blender 2.69?

Blender 2.69 shows, in the outline view, textures attached to a material:

[image: Blender 2.69 outline view of the document]

I need those same textures attached, to the same objects in the same way, for the same document opened in Blender 3.4.1.

When I look at the Outliner, it doesn't show any textures attached:

[image: Blender 3.41 outline view of the document]

The reason has been explained as a change introduced in Blender 2.8.

I don't need the Outliner to look the same but I do need the equivalent relationships: textures applied, with whatever settings or attributes are needed, so they work exactly the same way (compared to Blender 2.69) when rendered by Blender 3.41.

I've been [told I need to **manually re-create those associations**](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/302117/reliable-upgrade-for-blender-2-69-documents-to-blender-3-4/302131#302131) in Blender 3.4.1, using Nodes.

So I need to do this carefully, for hundreds of textures, in documents that I am totally unfamiliar with. I just need to have these upgraded so I can work with them in Blender 3.4.1.

There are textures available in the UV Editing tool. How do I discover exactly which ones should be associated where, and then how to I re-create the same effect using Nodes?

Comment: If your goal is displaying a tree-like view of dependencies like the first image illustrated I don't think Blender 2.9+ has that, you may get a vaguely similar breakdown directly from the material editor if you expand the nodes, but it only works on Cycles materials. If you goal is to convert materials from Blender Internal to Cycles, there are scripts that can help with that. See https://blenderartists.org/t/materials-specials-conversion/ if it still works in modern versions of Blender